# Reorganizing ManyToMany models into a different order

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I have an setup similar to this.

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Now in my admin panel I can select an author and add Books underneath that specific author. When I print out all the books for each author it prints them in the order that they were added in the admin panel.

Is it possible to modify the order in the admin panel so that when they print, they print in the order of the admin panel?

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(Author)
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

@admin.register(Book)
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add inside every model a class Meta with ordering atribute, to get items in a certain order.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['author']
```

Maybe it helps you.

Comment: Is it possible to setup ordering within the admin panel? Doing it that way I have to know what is going to be added. So if I added 10 books to the author, I would need to go to models.py and specify the exact order.

Answer (score 0):

as i understand you use `TabularInline` for books if that's right so you just need to make simple function called `get_queryset`

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    return super(BookInlineAdmin, self).get_queryset(request).order_by('YOURFIELD')
```

Comment: I don't know where how or how to use this. I basically want to open Book in the admin panel. I still a list of all my books. Then I want to rearrange them in any order I want.

Comment: Please share your admin.py file

Comment: Added the admin.py file

Comment: ok, so add this function to Books class
```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    return super(BookAdmin, self).get_queryset(request).order_by('YOURFIELD')
```

Comment: So doing it that way will just give me the list of items in a alphabetically order. But the above answer actually reposition everything alphabetically.

Comment: the both will work ... the difference the above solution will make it in this order everywhere inside admin and outside admin, but mine will customize the admin only